# How to drop row in pandas dataframe according to a condition on the index of the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called Prod with this shape:

```
carriers         electricity
techs   
ETH_imp          0.000000e+00
T:Arusha         1.786273e+06
T:Dar_es_Salaam  0.000000e+00
T:Dodoma         3.348339e+08
T:Geita          0.000000e+00
ccgt             3.412390e+08
```

So my `Prod.index` results in:

```
Index(['ETH_imp', 'T:Arusha', 'T:Dar_es_Salaam', 'T:Dodoma', 'T:Geita', 'ccgt'],
      dtype='object', name='techs')
```

I need to drop the rows, whose indexes contain the string `'T:'`

I tried `Prod=Prod.drop(Prod['T:' in Prod.index].index)`,
but apparently the boolean inside square parenthesis, `'T:' in Prod.index` only returns one `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change logic - get all rows if not index values contains or starting by `T:`

So filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `~` for invert mask with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df1 = Prod[~Prod.index.str.contains('T:')]
```

Or [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df1 = Prod[~Prod.index.str.startswith('T:')]
```

---

```
print (df1)
          electricity
carriers             
ETH_imp           0.0
ccgt      341239000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html)

```
new_df=Prod[~Prod.index.str.match('T:')]
print(new_df)

          electricity
carriers             
ETH_imp           0.0
ccgt      341239000.0
```

Comment: To clarify, `Series.str.match` works well here because `match` specifically selects strings that start with the pattern.